# During accelerating rpm going up but not speed

Tags: transmission, hyundai, shifting, accent

I have a Hyundai Accent 2002 car. Recently, each time I hit the race paddle to accelerate, my RPM goes up, but not the actual speed of the car. Could anyone think of what's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/9174/37

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you have a standard shift transmission. If this is the case, your problem lies with a bad clutch. You'll need to get it replaced to fix the issue.

If this is an automatic transmission, you either have low fluid or your clutches/bands are fried, which would mean a replacement or rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! yes its a manual transmission car !! Does it also deal something with clogged air filter ?

Comment: @Shivam ... I do not see any way this would have anything to do with a clogged air filter. A clogged air filter would cause it not to accelerate at all. As you have surmised, when you step on the pedal to accelerate, the engine and vehicle speed should go up together. Also, when this happens (the slippage), you may smell what some consider smells like fried chicken ... strange but true.